How to prevent soft bodies entering other soft bodies
I've created a soft body simulation but a lot of soft bodies enter other soft body objects.
I've tried many suggestions and options but can't avoid this behavior.
Any advice please?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kX8vd4UxVxvzT3-I2gwyIwf42pPYzzuo/view?usp=sharing

the objects do not have enough geometry to deform properly and collision detection is therefore poor.

@Blunder So I guess you can give it as an answer?
